# ARGB is not defined in a default MFC project

Tags: mfc, gdi+

To replicate:

1. Start up VS2019 (same issue with VS2015).
2. Create an MFC project, name it `argb-test` and press finish so as to use the default settings.
3. Inside of argb-test.cpp, add after the last include:

   ```c++
   #include <gdipluspixelformats.h>
   ARGB x;
   ```
4. Compile

The compile fails and I'm not sure why.  Here is the output:

```
test-argb.cpp(16,7): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
test-argb.cpp(16,6): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'x'
```

Hovering over ARGB will give me:

[image: looks fine]

So it looks fine to me.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the namespace Gdiplus.

```
Gdiplus::ARGB x;
```

Comment: What? This works, but why? It doesn't say that in any documentation I could find online. I didn't even see a `namespace` keyword in the header file. Also, the IDE thinks everything is also fine.  How did you come up with this answer?

Comment: I had stumbled upon this when using `ALPHA_MASK` which uses an unqualified reference to `ARGB`.

Comment: I have no excuse, someone else uses it in our code with the namespace, and it was also highlighted with ReSharper C++.

Comment: Well, thanks for sharing.  Was stuck on this for an hour or more.

Comment: Turns out that all of the `gdiplus*.h` files are included by default and they are wrapped by a namespace in the `gdiplus.h` header.  I was able to find that out by setting the `/P` switch which tells the compiler to send the preprocessed text to a file and then look for the info from in there.

Comment: @adr: This is little known, but GDI+ has a C interface at its base ([GDI+ Flat API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-flatapi-flat)). Client code usually uses the C++ wrappers. To prevent name clashes between GDI+' C and C++ interfaces, all of the latter are placed inside the `Gdiplus` namespace.